# Looping through a MySQL query and an array of checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

All right, so I am being passed an array of checked items represented by their IDs through a $_GET request. For example, suppose the following form:

```
Question 1
[ ] Answer 1 [31]
[ ] Answer 2 [32]
[ ] Answer 3 [33]
[ ] Answer 4 [34]
```

Let's assume the user chose `Answer 2` and `Answer 4`, so the array that is passed contains `32` and `34`, respectively, symbolizing their IDs in the database. Now, I want to loop through a database query of ALL of the answers for this question and print back checkboxes. However, if an answer is the one they picked, I'd like to have the checkbox already checked, so that, by my example, the output would be:

```
Question 1
[ ] Answer 1 [31]
[x] Answer 2 [32]
[ ] Answer 3 [33]
[x] Answer 4 [34]
```

I guess I'm just a bit off on my looping structure... but here is what I started with:

```
// The array that gets passed
$curr_answer_id = $_GET['answer'];

$length = count($curr_answer_id);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch2)){
    for($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++){
        if($row['answer_id'] == $curr_answer_id[$j]){
            echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$curr_answer_id[$j]' checked>".$row['answer']."</input>";
        } else {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$curr_answer_id[$j]'>".$row['answer']."</input>";
        }
    }
        echo "<br \>";
}
```

However, this duplicates results for as many answers were checked. Aside from the duplicates, however, it functions fine. As in my previous example, the output is:

```
Question 1
[ ] Answer 1 [31]
[ ] Answer 1 [31]
[x] Answer 2 [32]
[ ] Answer 2 [32]
[ ] Answer 3 [33]
[ ] Answer 3 [33]
[ ] Answer 4 [34]
[x] Answer 4 [34]
```

How can I fix this using what I've got? If anyone can also lend me to a more efficient way to cycle through all of the data that would be great as well.

Thanks.

Comment: $curr_answer_id is an array of answer ids (containing 32 and 34?). I don't quite get how you'd be pulling a PHP array directly from a $_GET var

Comment: @editor: Yes, that is correct. The checkboxes are originally set up to have their name attribute be an array, and so when it is passed to PHP, it comes in the form of an array.

Comment: @editor: To further elaborate, here is what a jQuery serialize() call might give: "question=1&answer[]=32&answer[]=34".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that is the right solution for you?

```
$curr_answer_id = $_GET['answer'];

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch2))
{
    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$row['answer_id']."' ".(in_array($row['answer_id'], $curr_answer_id) ? " checked" : "").">".$row['answer']."</input>";
    echo "<br \>";
}
```

Not tested.

**Update**: replaced input value with `$row['answer_id']` instead of `$curr_answer_id[$j]`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure why I tried to loop through the passed array...

Comment: Yep, I figured that one out! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

The double output is obvious because for each of your resultset from the query, you are running a FOR loop the number of times equal to the number of responses by the user.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch2)){
    for($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++){
```

The WHILE loops through each row (31, 32, 33, 34) and the FOR loop then loops twice. If you'll send 3 answers in your GET request, you'll see each checkbox appearing 3 times.

A solution might be that inside the WHILE loop, you can use `in_array()` to check if $row['answer'] exists in $_GET['answer']. And accordingly decide if to check or uncheck the check-boxes.

Hope that helps.